# Will an iSCSI SAN perform well when connected to a 2232PP fabric extender?

Tags: cisco, fabric, cisco-nexus

I intend to rack up servers and iSCSI SANs and connect them to 2232PPs that are fabric extenders uplinked to 5548UPs on a distribution rack.

Will an iSCSI SAN perform well when connected to a 2232PP fabric extender?  Are there any special steps I need to take beyond configuring VLANs and QoS?

Comment: Configuring vLANs and QoS on the NICs and switching gear is sufficient to generally optimize your network for iSCSI. Whether this is enough to satisfy your performance needs is unanswerable giving the information in your Question.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @ChrisS, I have voted to delete my question.  I will take it away and come up with a way to reword it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you've not really given us a great deal of information and your question's a bit vague but if the question was 'how will the iSCSI work on a 2k extender compared to going directly into a 5k' then it depends on where your servers are. If they're connected to the 2k directly then there's little difference but if the servers are connected to the 5k (or further down that chain) then obviously you'll be introducing some, small, degree of latency as the SAN's further away. If I'm misunderstood your question then please come back with more detail and/or clarifications.

By the way an iSCSI network is still really a VLAN, as it uses a LAN-protocol, if it was FCoE or FC then it'd be a VSAN, sorry to be picky ;)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Chopper3.  Good point on VSAN, VLAN.  I'm green as spring grass when it comes to network gear and SANs so I genuinely appreciate your help and patience :)